# Printing the elements of list inline

Tags: regex, list, dart

Suppose I have a `list = [4, 1, 8, 3]`, I want to print all the elements of `list` in the same line like:

```
4 1 8 3
```

I checked this regular expression `^\[|,|\]` on regexr.com and it selected everything except the elements. So I was expecting

```
print(list.toString().replaceAll('^\[|,|\]', ''));
```

to match above output, but it outputs:

```
[4, 1, 8, 3]
```

How do achieve the desired output?

Note that I cannot have whitespace around the output so something like this won't work:

```
list.forEach((element) => stdout.write('$element '));
```

Edit: I got it to work with

```
  print(list
      .toString()
      .replaceAll(',', '')
      .replaceAll('[', '')
      .replaceAll(']', ''));
```

is this the best that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: If you just need to "convert" a *list* of integers into a *string* of space-separated numbers, you just need to use `list.join(" ")`. **I understand you just practice regex and hence is my regex answer below.**

You need to pass a RegExp compiled object to the `.replaceAll` to actually use a regex. Also, you need to use a raw string literal, or you will have to double your backslashes.

You can use

```
print(list.toString().replaceAll(new RegExp(r'^\[|,|\]'), ''));
```

Output: `4 1 8 3`.

Note your regex is equal to `^\[|[,\]]` that matches a `[` at the start of string, or a comma or `]` anywhere inside a string. You probably wanted to match `]` only at the end of string, `^\[|,|]$`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain more about "**Also, you need to use a raw string literal, or you will have to double your backslashes.**" ?

Comment: @happy_san Just look: `print('^\[|,|]');` => `^[|,|]`, `print('^\\[|,|]');` => `^\[|,|]`, and `print(r'^\[|,|]');` => `^\[|,|]`. The `r` prefix lets Dart know the backslashes do not form any string escape sequences and are treated as literal backslashes (that are used to form regex escapes, like `\[`, `\(`, `\d`, `\w`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `list.join(' ');` method to print all the elements with a space joining them. This will not put a space at the front or the end either.

It's also useful for creating comma-separated lists.

`list.join(', ');` creates a string with a comma & space separating each element